# excel vba fill comobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have to fill several comboboxes for my user form in vba but the combobox is not filled when I load the userform. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.Clear
    ComboBox1.AddItem "C-S-A"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "C-A-T"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "C-A-S"
    ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.List(0)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "C-S-A"
        Case "C-A-T"
        Case "C-A-S"
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I found the problem. It has to say "UserForm". I used the name of the user form.

Comment: I tried it and works like it should. Be sure you have a combobox named "ComboBox1". Also check if somewhere else the combobox is being cleared.

Comment: Yes it works. Was my mistake.

Comment: you should add and accept an answer so the question is remove from the unanswered list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the wrong name. It has to be UserForm_Initialize().